# How do I specify which key file to use for Git Push on PHP Fog?

Tags: php, git, ssh, phpfog

Following is my ~/.ssh/config contents

```
ForwardAgent yes

# Default PHP Fog user (name)
Host phpfog
HostName git01.phpfog.com
User git
IdentityFile /Users/Pk_2/.ssh/id_rsa_phpfog


# Default github
Host github.com
User git
Hostname github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile /Users/Pk_2/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But when i try to do a git push on a phpfog repo folder it gives me

```
Permission denied(public key)
fatal:the  remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But Unless i rename id_rsa_phpfog to id_rsa i can't push to phpfog. So can i specify the key file

PHPFog config - http://docs.phpfog.com/getting-started/ssh/

Answer (score 1):

Your project's .git/config may need to be edited to allow the origin to use the host you defined in the ~/.ssh/config

Edit your `< project folder >/.git/config` file

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = <ssh-config-host>:<app_name_here>
```

If your apps name is www.example.com then the url line would look like:

```
url = phpfog:www.example.com
```

**Alternatively** you could also re-clone your app using the host you defined:

```
git clone phpfog:www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `~/.ssh/config` file, there is an additional line in each "Host" definition:

```
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

And git works happily with different key for different host.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ssh phpfog -vvv
```

To get debug output of what ssh is doing when it tries to connect. if you're using a different key you should see something like

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/<yourusername>/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for phpfog
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
...
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/<yourusername>/.ssh/id_rsa_phpfog
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
```

If you don't see anything that mentions `id_rsa_phpfog` you're either not using the hostname  you've defined in your `.ssh/config` file or the file isn't in the right place.

If all that looks correct it's most likely the public key you've added on phpfog isn't correct (doesn't exactly match your own public key)